# Intent Extras.getString() not comparing correctly -- Android

Tags: android, android-intent, extras

I have an Activity called searchProcedures which allows a user to select from a listview of medical procedures. I navigate to this activity from two other activities called searchHome and describeVisit. I needed a way for searchProcedures to know which activity it should navigate back to onClick. So I pass an intent.extra from searchHome or describeVisit (key:"sentFrom" value""). Then in searchProcedures I use the following code to determine which class to navigate to.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(!extras.isEmpty()){
        if(extras.containsKey("sentFrom")){
            if(extras.getString("sentFrom") == "searchHome"){
                returnIntent = new Intent(searchProcedures.this, searchHome.class);
            }
            else if(extras.getString("sentFrom") == "describeVisit"){
                returnIntent = new Intent(searchProcedures.this, describeVisit.class);
            }
            else{
                Log.d("failed", "the value of getString is " + extras.getString("sentFrom"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Checking the Log values, the correct values are being passed to and from activity, but when I check `extras.getString("sentFrom") == "searchHome/describeVisit"` it comes back as false, and returnIntent remains un-initialized. I have tried putting .toString after the .getString to no avail.

Comment: Show your passing intent code. You need to pass a string value with the key "sentfrom" inorder to obtain it as "getString("")" in the other activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

== compares the object references, not the content

You should use:

```
"searchHome".equals(extras.getString("sentFrom"))
```

Remeber to check blank space,...

**2.**

You can use a static variable in your SearchProceduresActivity to check where it comes from

SearchProceduresActivity

```
public static int sFrom = SEARCHHOME;
```

SearchHomeActivity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SearchHomeActivity.this, SearchProceduresActivity.class);
SearchProceduresActivity.sFrom = SEARCHHOME;
startActivity(myIntent);
```

DescribeVisitActivity:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(DescribeVisitActivity.this, SearchProceduresActivity.class);
SearchProceduresActivity.sFrom = DESCRIBEVISIT;
startActivity(myIntent);
```

SEARCHHOME, DESCRIBEVISIT value is up to you

Hope this help!

Comment: Great idea using the static variable - I didn't actually know that was an option! I think I'll use that

Answer (score 0):

String compare should use equal not ===